# Stack Overflow Behaviour in Native Languages

Tags: memory-management, native, stack-overflow, undefined-behavior, variable-length-array

I'm curious to why most natives languages, including C,C++ and D, doesn't define stack-overflow behaviour. Is it because it would require instrumenting every stack variable allocation and function call which, in turn, would make the code unusably slow? Evenso, it could at least be enabled only when compiler was fed some extra verbose debugging flag.

I'm asking this because I feel dubious over use of C99 variable length arrays (VLA) and C function `alloca` when writing C++ code. For some memory handling intensive algorithms this can result in significant speedups.

I'm guessing this question has been asked many times but I can't seem to find a relevant article on stackexchange.

Comment: In C at least, even the *existence* of the stack isn't even required by the standard.  That makes standardized stack overflow handling a bit much to ask.  Plenty of operating systems and other environments do provide such support, though.

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion, the reason is that high level languages - in contrast to assembler - are supposed to be as far as possible independent of the hardware the programs are executed on. They provide the programmer with the means to formulate a problem, but leave it to the compiler to use the hardware in an optimal way.
So the concept of a stack is something that a high level programmer should not be bothered with, neither how many registers the machine has, nor if it has a multicore CPU or not.